# how to identify missing dates in a sequence & impute it

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe where the columns are dates in sequence(say for nov). However I do see that there are some missing because they had no data as below:-

```
           2019-11-01   2019-11-02  2019-11-03  2019-11-05  2019-11-8  
  abc        5             3           54         9           9
  bcl        20           12           22         21           17
```

In the above dataframe, dates like 4th,6th,7th are missing. I want then to also be introduced as column with no values(NaN).

Here I gave only until 8th, however all dates of the month are supposed to be columns.

Can anyone please help me in getting this done in python.

Answer (score 2):

Convert your `columns` to `DatetimeIndex`, find the missing months and fill it:

```
df.columns = pd.to_datetime(df.columns)

month_range = pd.date_range(min(df.columns),max(df.columns),freq="D")

missing = [i for i in month_range if not i in df.columns]

df = pd.concat([df, pd.DataFrame(columns=missing)],axis=1, sort=False)
df = df[sorted(df.columns)]

print (df)
```

Or if you can afford to transpose:

```
df.columns = pd.to_datetime(df.columns)

month_range = pd.date_range(min(df.columns),max(df.columns),freq="D")

print (df.T.reindex(month_range).T)


     2019-11-01  2019-11-02  2019-11-03 2019-11-04  2019-11-05 2019-11-06 2019-11-07  2019-11-08
abc           5           3          54        NaN           9        NaN        NaN           9
bcl          20          12          22        NaN          21        NaN        NaN          17
```

Comment: can this be sorted again, such that 4th appears exactly between 3 & 5 , so does 6th & 7th appears between 5th & 8th

Comment: Just sort on columns.

Comment: there is an issue , which is thats the above code is only checking in that range. What if i want it for the whole month & I see the last say missng. The range between Max & min would not help because the Max would be 29th acording to pd.date_range(min(df.columns),max(df.columns),freq="D")

Comment: `month_range = pd.date_range(min(df.columns),max(df.columns)+pd.offsets.MonthEnd(0),freq="D")`. Also remember you can upvote or accept the answer if it helped.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the column with below line. use `fillna()` to have filled with NaN.

```
pd.date_range('2019-11-01', periods=30, freq='D')
```

```
DatetimeIndex(['2019-11-01', '2019-11-02', '2019-11-03', '2019-11-04',
               '2019-11-05', '2019-11-06', '2019-11-07', '2019-11-08',
               '2019-11-09', '2019-11-10', '2019-11-11', '2019-11-12',
               '2019-11-13', '2019-11-14', '2019-11-15', '2019-11-16',
               '2019-11-17', '2019-11-18', '2019-11-19', '2019-11-20',
               '2019-11-21', '2019-11-22', '2019-11-23', '2019-11-24',
               '2019-11-25', '2019-11-26', '2019-11-27', '2019-11-28',
               '2019-11-29', '2019-11-30'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='D')
```

Code to rename columns

```
data.columns = # list of Dates
```